# JSP Document/JSPX: what determines how tabs/space/linebreaks are removed in the output?

Tags: java, jsp, line-breaks, jspx

I've got a "JSP Document" ("JSP in XML") nicely formatted and when the webpage is generated and sent to the user, some linebreaks are removed.

Now the really weird part: apparently the "main" .jsp always gets *all* its linebreak removed but for any subsequent .jsp included from the main .jsp, linebreaks seems to be randomly removed (some are there, others aren't).

For example, if I'm looking at the webpage served from Firefox and ask to *"view source"*, I get to see what is generated.

So, what determines when/how linebreaks are kept/removed?

This is just an example I made up... Can you force a .jsp to serve this:

```
<body><div id="page"><div id="header"><div class="title">...
```

or this:

```
<body>
  <div id="page">
    <div id="header">
      <div class="title">...
```

?

I take it that linebreaks are removed to save on bandwidth, but what if I want to keep them?  And what if I want to keep the same XML indentation as in my .jsp file?

Is this doable?

**EDIT**

Following skaffman's advice, I took a look at the generated .java files and the "main" one doesn't have lots of *out.write* but not a single one writing tabs nor newlines.  Contrary to that file, all the ones that I'm including from that main .jsp have lots of lines like:

```
out.write("\t...\n");
```

So I guess my question stays exactly the same: what determines how tabs/space/linebreaks are included/removed in the output?

Comment: Have a look at the `.java` files that get generated from the JSP by the appserver, that might give you a clue as to why it's making these decisions.

Comment: Are you using `<jsp:include>` or `<% include %>`? Are you specifying content-type headers on any of them? Are the file extensions different?

Comment: @skaffman: thanks a lot for helping me with this.  <jsp:include> everywhere.  All files are named ".jsp".  The content type is the same on all of them (AFAIK subsequent trials to set the content type are perfectly valid and results in them being ignored so it is not an issue to include .jsp re-setting headers).  It's really as if all tabs/newlines were removed from the first .jsp but as if some tabs/newlines were kept from the .jsp included using <jsp:include.   But even there: it doesn't seem consistent.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As per the [JSP specification](https://jsp.dev.java.net/spec/jsp-2_1-fr-spec.pdf):

> #### JSP.6.2.3 Semantic Model
>
> ...
>
> To clearly explain the processing of whitespace, we follow the structure of the
> XSLT specification. The first step in processing a JSP document is to identify the
> nodes of the document. **Then, all textual nodes that have only white space are
> dropped from the document; the only exception are nodes in a jsp:text element,
> which are kept verbatim.** The resulting nodes are interpreted as described in the
> following sections. Template data is either passed directly to the response or it is
> mediated through (standard or custom) actions.

So, if you want to preserve whitespace, you need to wrap the desired parts in `<jsp:text>`.

Comment: +1 too... That said I tried to wrap in jsp:text and it didn't work (interestingly the person, much more knowledgeable on the subject than me, that asked the question that Pascal Thivent quoted, also asks if jsp:text could work... It is so easy to try that I take it he couldn't make jsp:text to work neither!?).  Anyway, +1 too and thanks for the spec quote/link.

Comment: Which JSP/Servlet container are you using? Which Servlet version is declared in web.xml?

Comment: Tomcat 6.0.26 (local testing): it was 2.4/JSP spec 2.0, changed to 2.5 and now the <jsp:text> tag works.  Thanks a *lot* :)

Comment: btw I still haven't fully why some .jsp where having their whitespaces/newlines removed and others not but in any case now using jsp:text I can force the behavior I need so it's all good :)

Answer (score 2):

Not a very precise answer but according to [this message](http://www.mail-archive.com/tomcat-user@jakarta.apache.org/msg156537.html), Jasper might be doing this (I admit I didn't check myself):

> I had a search around, and don't think
>   this one has been asked before.
>
> I've been writing my JSP pages as XML
>   documents (.jspx suffix), and one
>   difference that annoys me a little
>   between using the terse XML document
>   syntax and the (pre-2.0) legacy syntax
>   are line breaks, or lack of in the
>   former.
>
> The processed XML document results in
>   the XHTML where the tags are unbroken
>   by either spacing or line breaks.
>
> I understand fully the concept behind
>   why this is the case; the first XML
>   document is parsed down to it's node
>   tree, and then the XHTML is generated
>   based on this tree.
>
> However, I am of the understanding
>   that the white spacing doesn't have to
>   be lost along the way. I checked the
>   jasper code, particularly
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node, and a
>   cursory inspection reveals a lot of
>   .trim() calls, that may be
>   unnecessarily removing the spacing.
>   However, I am not so familiar with
>   this code to say decisively.
>
> In summation, this may be a bug/area
>   of improvement. Regardless, is there a
>   way to embed line breaks via
>   configuration? I feel confident to be
>   able to achieve these with ugly, ugly
>   CDATA sections, or some like technique
>   (jsp:text?)... but before I go to that
>   trouble, is there an easier/neater
>   way?

The message is pretty old but the same behavior is also reported in [this comment](http://raibledesigns.com/rd/entry/trim_spaces_in_your_jsp1#comment-1186051418000) and your question seems to imply it still applies.

Not sure you can change this behavior (without using a Filter).

Answer (score 0):

```
<trim-directive-whitespaces>true</trim-directive-whitespaces>
```

Whitespace inside `<jsp:text>` is stripped if you use the above directive in your `web.xml`. Given the semantic model quoted in [BalusC's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2935093/jsp-document-jspx-what-determines-how-tabs-space-linebreaks-are-removed-in-the-o/2935380#2935380), this directive is only useful if you're not using XML syntax.

*(Tomcat 6.0.16; Servlet 2.5 declarations; JSP 2.1 declarations in XML syntax)*