# Why JSPX does not like empty elements?

Tags: html, jsp, xhtml, jspx

this  `<div id="adiv"></div>` will in JSPX somehow be translated into `<div id="adiv" />`. The way I got it to work is to add empty comments inside like `<div id="adiv"><!--   --></div>`. I dont understand why this is happening and is there a better to solve this issue?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's by [JSP specification](https://jsp.dev.java.net/spec/jsp-2_1-fr-spec.pdf):

> #### JSP.6.2.3 Semantic Model
>
> ...
>
> To clearly explain the processing of whitespace, we follow the structure of the
>   XSLT specification. The first step in processing a JSP document is to identify the
>   nodes of the document. **Then, all textual nodes that have only white space are
>   dropped from the document; the only exception are nodes in a jsp:text element,
>   which are kept verbatim.** The resulting nodes are interpreted as described in the
>   following sections. Template data is either passed directly to the response or it is
>   mediated through (standard or custom) actions.

In *theory*, it should not harm if you use a XHTML doctype to present the document in the client side instead of a HTML doctype. However, even the XHTML spec requires some elements to be not self-closing. Another workaround would be using `<jsp:text />` instead of a comment.

```
<div id="adiv"><jsp:text /></div>
```

JSP(X) is however an old view technology. Its successor, [Facelets](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/giepx.html), does a better job in this.

#### See also:

- [JSP Document/JSPX: what determines how tabs/space/linebreaks are removed in the output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2935093/jsp-document-jspx-what-determines-how-tabs-space-linebreaks-are-removed-in-the)
- [Why don't self-closing script tags work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69913/why-dont-self-closing-script-tags-work)