# How to produce whitespace after trimDirectiveWhitespaces="true"?

Tags: jsp

After setting `<%@page trimDirectiveWhitespaces="true"%>`,  *all the whitespace* is stripped, even the space between `${a} ${b}`.

How can I produce *some* whitespace in my JSP? Like the space between `${a} ${b}` ?

**==EDIT==**

I know *why* the spaces are stripped, and I know that the official 'solution' is to *"wrap the desired spaces in `<jsp:text>`"*, but that impacts readability of my code. Would like to know if there is a more concise solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2935093/413020 and valid answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2935380/413020. In summary: use `<jsp:text>`

Comment: [THE DOCTOR](http://stackoverflow.com/users/70015/the-doctor)'s answer also works for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For now I'm using this code to print out a space: `${' '}`

Like this: `${a} ${' '} ${b}`

Answer (score 2):

You could get around this by using the JSTL c:out tag: `<c:out value="${a} ${b}" />`